# Flutter - Trouble preserving focus between routes

Tags: focus, flutter

I have a form that uses `FocusNode`s to visually indicate which part of the form is active. One field extends a PopupRoute as a kind of pop up 'keyboard'. My problem is, when I press that field, the keyboard pops up but the visual effect of the focus doesn't occur.

Some debugging from the `FocusNode`'s listeners shows it gets focus but immediately loses it. I think it is because the new `PopupRoute` has a new `FocusScopeNode`, so my `FocusNode` doesn't have focus any more.

How can I keep the field focused while in the other route? I've tried:

- Using `FocusScope.of(context).reparentIfNeeded(focusNode)` in all the build methods, which didn't do anything (I don't really understand this function tbh)
- Passing the current `FocusScope.of(context)` into my custom `PopupRoute` to use. This actually worked, but after it's popped, I can't focus anything anymore (I guess it gets disposed?)

Code-wise, I'm calling `requestFocus` on the field tap, and adding this listener in initState:

```
    widget.focusNode.addListener(() {
      print(widget.focusNode);
      if (widget.focusNode.hasFocus) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          CustomKeyboardPopupRoute(
            state: widget.state,
            position: //position stuff,
            focusScopeNode: FocusScope.of(context), //the second of my ideas which didn't quite work above
          )
        ).then((_) {
           widget.focusNode.unfocus();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, indeed this happens because of the `FocusScopeNode`.

Make your keyboard route extend `TransitionRoute`:

```
class CustomKeyboardPopupRoute extends TransitionRoute {
  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  @override
  Iterable<OverlayEntry> createOverlayEntries() sync* {
    yield OverlayEntry(
      opaque: false,
      maintainState: true,
      builder: _buildKeyboard,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
    final positionAnimation = Tween(begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0), end: Offset.zero).animate(animation);
    return SlideTransition(position: positionAnimation, child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: ...
    ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I was also able to preserve the "tap away to close" behaviour (which was why I used `PopupRoute`) by `yield`ing a `ModalBarrier` before the `_buildKeyboard`

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How can a custom transition have anything to do with FocusScope?  cc @Lucas

Comment: the transitions don't have anything to do with it. but when you define a custom route, you have to take care of the transitions.

The point of this answer: If you want to keep focus in a `TextField` of the parent route, you cannot use `PopupRoute` for your custom keyboard.

Comment: They extend the parent class differently, and one difference is `PopupRoute` creates a new `FocusScopeNode` and `TransitionRoute` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much.

```
Iterable<OverlayEntry> createOverlayEntries() sync* {
    yield OverlayEntry(
      opaque: false,
      maintainState: true,
      builder: (content) {
        return ModalBarrier(dismissible: true);
      }
    );
    yield OverlayEntry(
      opaque: false,
      maintainState: true,
      builder: _buildContent,
    );
  }
```