# FocusScope messed up by Navigator

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm writing a simple reminder app that is essentially a `ListView` of `TextField`s that, when blurred or submitted, update the database. I use a bunch of `GestureDetector`s and `FocusNode`s to blur the `TextField` when a user taps on the checkbox or outside the `TextField`.

It works very well when this is the only route. However, when I push the same exact page on top of the existing one, the focus behavior becomes completely buggy and the app unusable.

Here's a video to demonstrate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13E9LY8yD3A

My code is essentially this:

```
/// main.dart

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static FocusScopeNode rootScope; // just for debug

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    rootScope = FocusScope.of(context);
    return MaterialApp(home: ReminderPage());
  }
}
```

-

```
/// reminder_page.dart

class ReminderPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _blurNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Remind'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              // Push new identical page.
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ReminderPage(),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('reminders').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return _buildBody(context, snapshot.data);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, QuerySnapshot data) {
    List<Reminder> reminders =
        data.documents.map((s) => Reminder.fromSnapshot(s)).toList();
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _blur(context);
      },
      child: ListView(
        children: reminders.map((r) => ReminderCard(r)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _blur(context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_blurNode);
  }
}
```

-

```
/// reminder_card.dart

class ReminderCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Reminder reminder;
  final TextEditingController _controller;
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final _blurNode = FocusNode();

  ReminderCard(this.reminder)
      : _controller = TextEditingController(text: reminder.text) {
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        reminder.updateText(_controller.text); // update database
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _blur(context);
      },
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildCheckBox(context),
          _buildTextField(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCheckBox(context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: reminder.done,
      onChanged: (done) {
        print(MyApp.rootScope.toStringDeep()); // print Focus tree
        _blur(context);
        reminder.updateDone(done); // update database
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextField(context) {
    return TextField(
      onSubmitted: reminder.updateText, // update database
      focusNode: _focusNode,
    );
  }

  void _blur(context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_blurNode);
  }
}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022207/flutter-trouble-preserving-focus-between-routes) which sounds very similar, but I didn't understand how the custom transition solves anything and has anything to do with focus. And like the OP, I tried a lot of different things to mess with `FocusScope`, include call `detach()`, `reparentIfNeeded()`, or passing the `FocusScope` of the root all the way down so a new `FocusScope` is not created each time, but none of those gave anything close to working. And I also tried the custom transition, to no avail.

The debug output shows this on the first route (when I check boxes):

```
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362):        focus: FocusNode#f07c7(FOCUSED)
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362):        focus: FocusNode#f138f(FOCUSED)
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362):        focus: FocusNode#e68b3(FOCUSED)
```

And this on the second route:

```
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    ├─child 1: FocusScopeNode#a1008
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 2: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362):        focus: FocusNode#a76e6
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    ├─child 1: FocusScopeNode#a1008
I/flutter (28362):    │   focus: FocusNode#02ebf(FOCUSED)
I/flutter (28362):    │
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 2: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362):        focus: FocusNode#a76e6
I/flutter (28362): FocusScopeNode#68466
I/flutter (28362):  └─child 1: FocusScopeNode#5b855
I/flutter (28362):    ├─child 1: FocusScopeNode#a1008
I/flutter (28362):    │   focus: FocusNode#917da(FOCUSED)
I/flutter (28362):    │
I/flutter (28362):    └─child 2: FocusScopeNode#76ef6
I/flutter (28362):        focus: FocusNode#a76e6
```

So it looks like the FocusScope of the first route becomes child 2 when we push the second route, which sounds correct to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you focusing more than one thing at once? I don't think this is the intended use case for `FocusNode`. Is used to indicate what aspect of the UI is current selected or in focus, which often involves the keyboard. By design I think only one thing is meant to be focused at once. Is there a reason you aren't just using a bool `isBlurred`?

Comment: And then is you want to blur or unblurred based on the focus of the `TextField`, pass in your `FocusNode` (only one) and `listen()` to it

Comment: So right now I have 1 `FocusNode` for each `TextField` in a reminder card, and 1 `FocusNode` for the background of each reminder card. Additionally I have a `FocusNode` for the background of the whole page. Are you saying I should just have a `FocusNode` for each `TextField`, but a single background `FocusNode` shared by the page and all reminder cards?

Comment: You should only have one focus node per card (ie. per text field). Sorry, I was confused about your use of 'blur', now I realise you mean unfocusing. So the purpose of you managing the `FocusNode`s is to be able to update the database? In that case, you could just use `onChanged` without worrying about focusing. If you want to save api calls, then just use one `FocusNode` for each text field.

Comment: Additionally, you unfocus not by focusing a 'background' `FocusNode`, but by calling `myFocusNode.unfocus()`. Perhaps that is what is tripping you up.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Having only one focus node per card, and listening to onChanged on the controller rather than on the focus node, fixed two of my problems :) Turns out there were two more issues, which I could also solve. I'll summarize everything in an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas' comments above and [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293173/flutter-app-page-constantly-rebuilding) I was able to fix the problem.

First, I reduced the number of `FocusNode`s: just one per `TextField`, and one for the parent `ReminderPage`. The parent now has a function `blur()` that unfocuses all `TextField`s; that way, when I click the checkbox of a `TextField` while editing another, the one being edited is unfocused.

Second, I changed my `reminder.updateText()` function (not shown here) so it only updates the database when the text is different from the existing text. Otherwise, we would be rebuilding the card because of the `StreamBuilder`, messing up the focus of the `TextField` being edited.

Third, I'm now listening to the `TextEditingController` instead of the `FocusNode` to make changes to the database. But I still only update the database when the `FocusNode` is unfocused, otherwise the `StreamBuilder` would rebuild the page and mess up with focus again.

But that still doesn't explain why it works reasonably well when the `ReminderPage` is the homepage of the app, and not when it's pushed on top of a route. The answer comes from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293173/flutter-app-page-constantly-rebuilding) which was hitting the same issue: the widget was constantly rebuilt when placed after a splash screen, but not when used as the app homepage. I still don't understand why this makes any difference, but the same fix worked for me: **change it to StatefulWidget and only rebuild when something actually changed**.

The final code looks like this. I highlighted the diffs with `// --->` comments.

```
/// main.dart

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: ReminderPage());
  }
}
```

-

```
/// reminder_page.dart

class ReminderPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _blurNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Remind'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              // Push new identical page.
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ReminderPage(),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('reminders').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return _buildBody(context, snapshot.data);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, QuerySnapshot data) {
    List<Reminder> reminders =
        data.documents.map((s) => Reminder.fromSnapshot(s)).toList();
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // ---> Blur all TextFields when clicking in the background.
        blur(context);
      },
      child: ListView(
        // ---> Passing the parent to each child so they can call parent.blur()
        children: reminders.map((r) => ReminderCard(r, this)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  // ---> This will unfocus all TextFields.
  void blur(context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_blurNode);
  }
}
```

-

```
/// reminder_card.dart

// ---> Converted to a StatefulWidget! That way we can save a snapshot of reminder
// as it was when we last built the widget, and only rebuild it if it changed.
class ReminderCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Reminder reminder;
  final TextEditingController _controller;

  // ---> Only one focus node, for the TextField.
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();

  // ---> The parent.
  final ReminderPage page;

  ReminderCard(this.reminder, this.page)
      : _controller = TextEditingController(text: reminder.text) {
    // ---> Listen to text changes. But only updating the database
    // if the TextField is unfocused.
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        reminder.updateText(_controller.text); // update database
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  ReminderCardState createState() => ReminderCardState();
}

class ReminderCardState extends State<ReminderCard> {
  Widget card;
  Reminder snapshotWhenLastBuilt;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ---> Only rebuild if something changed, otherwise return the
    // card built previously.
    // The equals() function is a method of the Reminder class that just tests a
    // few fields.
    if (card == null || !widget.reminder.equals(snapshotWhenLastBuilt)) {
      card = _buildCard(context);
      snapshotWhenLastBuilt = widget.reminder;
    }
    return card;
  }

  Widget _buildCard(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // ---> Blur all TextFields when clicking in the background.
        widget.page.blur(context);
      },
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildCheckBox(context),
          _buildTextField(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCheckBox(context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: widget.reminder.done,
      onChanged: (done) {
        // ---> Blur all TextFields when clicking on a checkbox.
        widget.page.blur(context);
        widget.reminder.updateDone(done); // update database
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextField(context) {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: widget._focusNode,
      controller: widget._controller,
    );
  }
}
```